# How to enforce a method argument type?

Tags: typescript, generics, marker-interfaces

How to enforce that types are part of a super type, that has no properties? The idea is to enforce that only types that share a super type can be passed to a method and no other types.

Assume we have different types that are intended to update something.

```
type DateUpdateObj= {newDate:Date}
type LengthUpdateObj= {newLength:number, unit: 'm'|'cm'}
type ...UpdateObj = {...} //it should be possible to add many more Update Objects types
```

A function should only accept sub-types as argument. But how to do it properly?

My first attempt was to use some kind of marker interface (UpdateObj) like in Java or Kotlin.

```
class UpdateObj { private readonly _ :never} // acts as a marker interface
type MyUpdateObj = { foo:string} & UpdateObj  //the new update obj type
 
function send<T extends UpdateObj>(updateObj:T){} //the function only accepts UpdateObj
```

Compile test:

```
send("") //ok, doesn't compile as expected
send(new Date())  //ok, doesn't compile as expected
send({foo:'hurray'} as MyUpdateObj) //ok, compiles es expected

const myUpdate:MyUpdateObj=  { foo:"err"} //should compile but doesn't, since '_' is missing and adding a cast is not possible in my case cause it would break source compatibility
send(myUpdate)
```

## [TSPlayground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-eblCB2ErQxiUIhknAjMrmI6oBZkkqbXbsqBOKdigB9SaEZpEJrCAPB2BGIzDmDKxpK-tQUudRBDizqvZ8-DjZIQafb4gwLfQfJQZxVmuNgYwGgYqvSLsO3SECwR-J8FRMVgfDY3ek4PNi6x2B0SY4EaGTSEa8xxli1IbuSzJAA)

Comment: could you add more tests which should fail? Right now, one could remove the marker interface and all tests would pass.

Comment: everything that doesn't "has" the marker interface should not compile when it is passed to the method. maybe there are other tricks than a marker interface/class or whatever.

Comment: Your "marker interface" is really just `{}` since it has no public properties. Anything excluding `null` and `undefined` is assignable to `{}`.

Comment: nop { private readonly _ :never} in not the same as {}, since { private readonly _ :never} disallows anything that is not casted to the marker type, i added a stackblitz, hopefuly it helps

Comment: I believe you answered your own answer: "should compile but doesn't, since '_' is missing". I also don't understand the point of the marker interface, which is not an interface but a class in your example. And you cannot have a readonly property which is not initialized. And you cannot have a private property in a type.

Comment: I want to ensure that only sub-types of UpdateObject can be passed to the method and nothing else. In Java you simply let subtypes implement the empty marker interface that is also uses as method argument type. My question is how to something eqivalent in typescript.